# Validating Auto renewing subscription receipt on the server

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

I am implementing auto renewing subscription over a period of one month.
I was thinking of storing the expiration date and validate again when this date is reached (i.e .validate once a month per subscribed user).

But what about cancellation? A user could potentially cancel his subscription and be refunded by Apple any time during the one month period, and I would not be notified.

Should I then validate the receipt as often as possible (e.g. every day) to check for a cancellation date?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a awesome class that does all the magic for you without the use of a server. It simple checks if the user still has paid the subscription every time when opening the app by calling a function in your app's delegate:

https://github.com/SahebRoy92/SRSubscriptionModel

Comment: First of all, I must validate the receipt on the server because my service is also available on other platforms than iOS. If a user subscribes on iOS and never uses the app again, I want to keep on validating on my server so the user can use the web service.

Comment: Secondly, I don't see any validation in this class. If you want to validate the receipt client side, this is the way you should do it: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW2